# pymongo v3.10, MongoClient gets pyCharm error "cannot import name 'MongoClient" with "from pymongo import MongoClient", in Windows

Tags: pycharm, importerror

I have Python 3.5.1, pyCharm 2020.1.2 on Win 7, and I installed pymongo 3.5.1 and upgraded it to 3.10.1
I continuously have ImportError: cannot import name 'MongoClient' error after the
"from pymongo import MongoClient" line.

I started by installing pymongo  with "pip install pymongo" in command window, got error in executing import command.
After checking the answers on Web I followed with

"pip uninstall pymongo"
"python -m pip install pymongo==3.5.1"
"python -m pip install --upgrade pymongo"

Now with pymongo v3.10.1 I got same error again. So, I

- restarted pyCharm
- deleted pymongo package from the project,executed three commands above, added pymongo to project.

After each of those operations - same error.
I looked into pymongo installation, it has mongo_client.py file, but changing MongoClient to mongo_client did not help.

What is wrong with this package?

Vladimir Kievsky,
vkievsky@hotmail.com

Comment: The version of **Python** you used to install **pymongo** with **pip** is different - it's not same as the one configured in your **Pycharm**. In your project setting in **Pycharm** verify the interpreter and the paths are configured for the right version of **Python**.

Comment: The pyCharm project python's  version is 3.5. The top python version is 3.9, so my version is close to the top. Can you please elucidate what do you mean by a  "right" version? What it has to be to avoid that error  and in what document that is described?

Comment: I mean this issue happens when Python you run in PyCharm's console or in Linx terminal where you run your **pip** and Python configured in your Project's settings *is* *not* *the* *same*- it can't be **close** - it has to be **exactly** **the** **same** interpreter installed in **exactly** **the** **same** **location** - Python's modules are installed per interpreter, not per version, so any time you use pip with different Python it goes into different interpreter and your other interpreters know nothing about versions and modules installed under different interpreter.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html